# tracking multiple objects on opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, cvblobslib

I want to track  mutiple objects using opencv on Visual Studio 2010, so I need the library cvblobslib, my problem is when I try to to build to provided VS project I get an error. can anbody tell me how I'm suppose to do that the right way

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to be a more specific, e.g., what error message do you get?

Comment: well when I compile the VS project to get the lib file , it just doesn't work

Comment: Which output do you get from the compilation in the output window? It's hard to help without more information.